# method main(String[]) is already defined

Tags: java, функции, return

> **ЗАДАНИЕ** Реализуйте функцию с сигнатурой `public String sayHello(String greeting, String name)` Функция принимает 2 параметра,
> приветствие и имя. Функция должна вернуть строку по шаблону:
> <приветствие>, <имя>! например: `sayHello("Привет", "Долли")` должна
> вернуть `"Привет, Долли!"`, `sayHello("Добрый день", "Марь Ивана")` должна вернуть `"Добрый день, Марь Ивана!"`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = sayHello("Привет, ", "Долли!");
    System.out.print(temp);
}

public String sayHello(String greeting, String name) {
    String a = greeting;
    String b = name;
    String result = (a,b);
    return result;
}
```

Выдало ошибку:

```
Syntax Error(s) __tester__.java:10: error: -> expected result = (a,b);
```

Comment: Уберите метод `main`. Оно, видимо, встраивает этот отрезок в подготовленный класс, где метод `main` уже есть (Он же и вызывает вашу ф-ю). Могу быть неправ - где вы выполняете это задание, не знаю

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    
    public static String sayHello(String greeting, String name) {
        return String.join("", greeting, ", ", name, "!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(sayHello("Привет", "Долли"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Syntax Error(s) __tester__.java:5: error: ';' expected
    return String join("", greeting, ", ", name, "!"); 1 error

Comment: @Den77 вы копируете код в класс, который уже содержит ошибку. я не вижу вашу среду разработки. удалите свой класс и создайте новый с именем Main , после чего скопируйте туда этот код

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за то, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос. По условиям задания класс не создается, а задание проверяет робот, с ним не обсудить вопросы.

Comment: @Den77 тогда копируйте код внимательно, поскольку в среде разработки все компилируется и выполняется

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, поможет или нет, у меня работает:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = sayHello("Привет, ", "Долли!");
        System.out.print(temp);
    }
    public static String sayHello(String greeting, String name) {
        return greeting + name;
    }
}
```

Если нужно, чтобы метод был нестатическим, тогда:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.print(test.sayHello("Привет, ", "Долли!"));
    }
    public String sayHello(String greeting, String name) {
        return greeting + name;
    }
}
```

Вывод в обоих случаях:

```
Привет, Долли!
```